# How to serialize differently the same properties of the same entity using jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Suppose you have this entity:

```
class Foo{
 String propA;
 String propB;
}
```

and you want to serialize for one API like :

```
{propA: "ola",
 propB: "Holla"}
```

and for another API like :

```
{fooPropA: "ola",
 fooPropB: "Holla"}
```

How can this be achieved using jackson and using the same entity. Creating 2 different entities is not an option :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways in which you can achieve this. You can enable a custom serializer (already covered by @se_vedem), register an annotation [introspector](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/AnnotationIntrospector) which changes the property names for the corresponding class and so on.

However, if you are willing to only add a string prefix to all the property names, then [the Jackson property name strategy](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeaturePropertyNamingStrategy) is probably the best fit. The naming strategy class has the access to the serialized object type information, so you can make a decision whether to change the property name or not.

Here is an example using a custom annotation that defines the prefix:

```
public class JacksonNameStrategy {
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public static @interface PropertyPrefix {
        String value();
    }

    @PropertyPrefix("foo_")
    public static class Foo {
        public String propA;
        public String propB;

        public Foo(String propA, String propB) {
            this.propA = propA;
            this.propB = propB;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new MyPropertyNamingStrategyBase());
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Foo("old", "Holla")));
    }

    private static class MyPropertyNamingStrategyBase extends PropertyNamingStrategy {

        @Override
        public String nameForField(MapperConfig<?> config,
                                   AnnotatedField field,
                                   String defaultName) {
            PropertyPrefix ann = field.getDeclaringClass().getAnnotation(PropertyPrefix.class);
            if (ann != null) {
                return ann.value() + defaultName;
            }
            return super.nameForField(config, field, defaultName);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"foo_propA":"old","foo_propB":"Holla"}
```

In your API method you choose between two `ObjectMapper` instances one with the default naming naming strategy and one with the custom one.

Comment: Good tip, but this would affect all entities serialized by that ObjectMapper. I was looking more for a way to isolate some entities, like only 2 out of 100 need this special serialization treatment.

Comment: @sa_vedem How do you want to distinguish between the entities? Based on the type information or a property value?

Comment: by that fact that one will be serialized using ObjectMapperA and the other using ObjectMapperB

Comment: @sa_vedem so affecting all entities by the ObjetMapper is fine, right?

Comment: I'm sorry, I answered completely bad at your first question. I'd like to distinguish them on type information.

Comment: @sa_vedem I have updated my answer to demonstrate how to access the type information inside the naming strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using modules feature from Jackson.

Basically, each API would have it's own ObjectMapper and they will be configured with different modules. This way you can create 2 serializers for the same class and register them on the appropriate module. More read can be found here http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureModules

However, be aware that serializers are loaded in a particular order. First it tries to get the annotated ones, if none is found it will try to get those registered from modules. So, for example if you have your class annotated with serializer, then that serializer(FooSerializer) would be chosen instead of the one configured in module(MySecondFooSerializer).

```
@JsonSerialize(using = FooSerializer.class)
class Foo{
 String propA;
 String propB;
}

module.addSerializer(Foo.class, new MySecondFooSerializer());
```